# Change the extension of previous uploaded files using Django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner')
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='my_files/%Y/%m/%d')
```

I need to change the extension of previously uploaded files using this model.

Comment: This question seems to be well answered here:
[How to replace/overwrite/update a file of filefield][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787141/django-how-to-replace-overwrite-update-change-a-file-of-filefield

Comment: mar7aba bro massri :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `upload_to` can be callable, like this:

```
import date
import os
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    d = date.today()
    parts = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'my_files/%s/%s/%s/%s.%s' % (
        d.year, d.month, d.day, parts[0], 'new_ext')
```

So, in your model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
   # ...
   myfile = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

This won't help you to handle files already uploaded in past, but new uploads will have correct names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine model's save method this way:

```
import os

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            prev_instance = Entry.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if prev_instance.myfile:
                 name = os.path.splitext(prev_instance.myfile)[0]
                 os.rename(prev_instance.myfile, name + ".old")
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```