# Django Media file auto-delete

Tags: django

When I upload an image through Django administrator and I delete the image file again, why does it not delete the image int the `/media` directory?

When I delete an image file, I want it to delete the image automatically  even from the directory, not only the model instance.

My model:

```
class ImageForExtractText(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()
```

And settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

What should I do to make it happen, when deleting the image file from Django administration? It should be deleted from both Django administration and the media directory.

Comment: There is already a similar question here, with many answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941503/django-delete-unused-media-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django doesn't delete the files on delete.

You can add a signal to delete the file:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

class ImageForExtractText(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=ImageForExtractText)
def delete_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    if instance.image:
        instance.image.delete(False)
```