# How to delete certain user image form database in Django?

Tags: python, django

Hello I need to delete some images of current logged in user from DB from html

here is my profile class

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image1 = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='images', blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='images', blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

thanks a lot

Comment: `some_profile.image1.delete()`. Note that the images are *not* stored in the database, the path of the files is stored in the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but will that delete only current logged in user images?

Comment: It will delete the image of the user `some_profile`.

Comment: @Arthur: you can obtain the `Profile` of the logged in user with `request.user.profile`, so `request.user.profile.image1.delete()`

Comment: I need to implement an ability of current logged in user to be able to delete his/her images only. So I think I need to query images by current logged in user id...

Comment: @Arthur: the profile of the current logged in user is `request.user.profile`, so then you can process that profile, for example by calling a `image1.delete()` on that profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete some reference to a file (with a `FileField`, or `ImageField`) with:

```
some_profile.image1.delete()
```

With `some_profile` the `Profile` object, and `image1` the name of the field of the file you want to delete.

So in a view, you can delete this with:

```
def some_view(request):
    try:
        request.user.profile.image1.delete()
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    # ...
```

This will *not* remove the file itself from the media directory. There are several [solutions to clean up media files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941503/django-delete-unused-media-files).