# replace the file associated with an imagefield without having django copying it

Tags: django

I have a userprofile of the form

```
class profile():
  #the next line is just an abstract
  profile_images='volumes/media/root/userprofile/profile_images/'
  image=models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_images)
```

in the directory "profile_images" there are the last 5 files the user uploaded as profile images, ie:

```
image_1
image_2
image_3
image_4
image_5
```

lets say the current profile.image is image_1. now i want to allow the user to select one of the previous images. the function i wrote to change the image to the one i received from the form looks like that:

```
def change_profile_image(userprofile,path_to_new_image):
  f = open(path_to_new_image, 'r')
  userprofile.image = ImageFile(f)
  userprofile.save()
```

as an example the user selects image_3, and after execution of that code the forementioned directory looks like that:

```
image_1
image_2
image_3
image_4
image_5
volumes/media/root/userprofile/profile_images/image_3
```

which, of course, is not what i wanted. what i want is to just change the file associated with the ImageField of my profile instance, without Django copying any files.
any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, actually it's as easy as

```
userprofile.image=path_to_new_image
```

no need to worry with opening files, deleting and rewriting them.

Comment: Does this upload the new file as well? Didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could overwrite userprofile.image.path, but it’s not too obvious how to do that.

Here is some more information.

[Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

[Django: How to replace/overwrite/update/change a file of FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787141/django-how-to-replace-overwrite-update-change-a-file-of-filefield)

[How can I replace/override an uploaded file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253860/how-can-i-replace-override-an-uploaded-file)

Comment: image.path is not writeable. and you posted exactly the questions that pointed me to my approach. as far as i can see it, i allready wrote the new file to userprofile.image. i just don't get a correct url back, when asking for userprofile.image.url i get (MEDIA_URL+absolute path to the file) as url.